# JS Turf, Check if Line is completely within polygon

Tags: javascript, line, polygon, intersection, turfjs

I have a single Turf Polygon and a Turf LineString. I need to check wether the line is completely within the polygon. the outer-Points of the line are allowed to be on the polygon border.

I've tried:

```
turf.difference(poly, line) === null

turf.booleanEquals(turf.intersect(poly, line), line)

turf.booleanContains(poly, line);
```

but nothing worked as intended.

Comment: So I solved it myself. You test for one point on the line being inside the polygon (there is a turf function for that) and then you test wether the line intersects any lines that make up the polygon.